# How to sum numbers that have matching strings

Tags: awk

I currently have a script that results in this file :

```
Score1 5
Score1 9
Score1 4
Score2 6
Score2 11
Score3 10
Score3 1
Score3 2
...
```

And then a number of other scores, in the hundreds.
I want to add up the numbers with that are prefaced by the same string, so the output should be :

```
Score1 18
Score2 17
Score3 13
...
```

I have the feeling the correct way to go about it is using awk, but after quite a bit of experimenting I haven't got a solution yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
awk '{a[$1] += $2}; END{for(c in a) print c, a[c]}' <file
```